# How to combine results from different CompletionStage in a for loop?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to combine values from multiple CompletionStage. What is the best way to combine the different CompletionStage. Currently I have

```
//Given
CompletionStage<Long> getCount(final String name);

CompletionStage<Boolean> isAnyOneGreaterThanOne(){

    final var futures = names.stream()
                             .map(name -> getCount(name))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    CompletionStage<Boolean> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
    for (final var future : futures){
       result = result.thenCombine(
                         futures.get(i), (previous, longValue) -> previous || (longValue > 0));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a neater/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
    CompletionStage<Boolean> result = names.stream()
            .map(this::getCount)
            .map(countFuture -> countFuture.thenApply(value -> value > 0))
            .reduce(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false), (current, next) -> current.thenCombine(next, Boolean::logicalOr))
```